# How do you refer to an image without using the file path?

Tags: java, image, jar

Currently, the way I am referring to my images are by using the lines of code:

```
 static ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("src\\img1.png");
 static ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("src\\img2.png");
```

However, when I export this from eclipse into a .jar file, the picture does not show up. Is it possible to refer to the image without setting the complete file path (ex. ("C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX.img1.jpg)), because if I put the .jar on a flash drive, the complete file path would be useless?

Comment: Use `Class#getResource`, for example `getClass().getResource("/img1.png`)`

Comment: Also, Java knows the path seperator on your system and will substitute it for any '/' in a path.  Your path above could be written as `"src/img1.png"` and it will then work on any system, Windows, *nix, etc.  As is it's hard coded to be Windows only,

Comment: @markspace Incorrect. Java doesn't do anything special for file paths. The only reason why you can use a forward slash on Windows is because Windows also allows it as a separator in addition to backslash. It's OS dependent. (Note that I'm talking about file paths, like in the question. *Resource* paths as in Class.getResource always use a forward slash)

Comment: @MadProgrammer how would I use this in this situation? Do you have any more information that might help?

Comment: @markspace Except you should never have a reference to `src` in part of your code ;)

Comment: @Zerukai `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img1.png"))`

Comment: @MadProgrammer when I do this, getClass() says that I may not make a static reference to a non-static method from the type Object. However, if I remove the static modifier, I am unable to reference img1 in multiple sections of the program.

Comment: @Zerukai `{your calss}.class.getResource(...)` ... don't get me started on the merits of `static`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you!!! Apologizes if I seemingly asked some stupid questions - I'm still learning. But that did solve the issue! Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the package contains image create any empty class Example : `ImageLoader`

When you want to load image :

```
   ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(ImageLoader.class.getResource("img1.png"));
```

ImageLoader.class.getResource : will return the URL of ImageLoader class